# In mobile version for sub menu open & collapse is overlapping with the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, adminlte

I am using adminlte 2 themes in that mobile version, opening & closing of the submenu is not working properly only for the first time, from next time it's working properly:

[image: Menu - sidebar]

Comment: Keep the z-index value of sub-menu more than the menu list.

Comment: No its still the very same for the first time, Have set submenu z-index to 2 and menu list to 1